# How do I suppress the noise associated with pressing RETURN in a textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have read that I can suppress this noise by defining a form accept button, which is something I am trying to avoid (I can point it at a hidden or inactive button I suppose, but since it's not explicitly what I'm trying to do, I'm concerned about side effects)

I use the following snippet to trap the return key and it works just fine, the noise does not occur if I click the button manually.

```
    private void urlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Return ) 
        //if ( e.KeyValue.Equals(13) )
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            //e.Handled = true;
            goButton.PerformClick();
        }
```

I am targetting .NET 4.0 so I should be able to implement most ideas.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Your PC makes a noise when you click on a WinForms button?

Comment: @DOK No, when I press enter in a non-multiline textbox which triggers a KeyDown event which then calls a PerformClick() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
private void urlTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {                
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
private void urlTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        goButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4970.htm)

It may also work with the `KeyDown` event but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I put in the necessary `this.urlTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(urlTextBox_KeyPress);` and `this.urlTextBox.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(urlTextBox_KeyUp);` and it works as expected.  Can you explain a little *why*?

Comment: Unfortunately no... maybe to let the user know that their keypress was suppressed programmatically to avoid support calls to MS saying that Windows is missing key presses?